# 3-D Geometry - line

Tags: vectors, 3d

**Question:**

> A line makes the same angle $\theta$ with the x and z-axis. If the angle $\beta$ which it makes with the y-axis is such that $\sin^2\beta = 3\sin^2\theta$ then find the value of $\cos^2\theta$.

As I know that the angle made with x and z-axis is the same, I can assume the line to be parallel to a vector: $a\hat i + b\hat j + a\hat k$

So I know that: $$\cos \theta = \frac{a}{\sqrt{2a^2 + b^2}}$$ $$\cos \beta = \frac{b}{\sqrt{2a^2 + b^2}}$$

When I attempt to solve this (using the relation of the sines given), I get:
$$3b^2 = -a^2$$
Which doesn't seem to be right. Any hints?

Comment: You're forgetting the square roots in the denominators.

Comment: @Rahul There fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If *'a line makes the same angle $\theta$ with the x and z-axis'* then $\theta$ is at least a half of a right angle (when the line lies in $OXZ$ plane as a bisector of the first quarter), then its sine is at least $\sqrt 2/2$ and $$3\sin^2\theta \ge 1.5$$

And no $\beta$ satisfies $$\sin^2\beta \ge 1.5$$

Comment: Answer is 3/5 so....

Comment: So...? So try to obtain it. My calculations ended, similary to yours, with $2a^2=3(a^2+b^2)$, which implies $-a^2=3b^2$. Are you sure you copied the problem wording correctly?

Comment: Yep. The question is correct. And yes, I end up with the same thing... Had a calculation error before.